# How to remove garbage values or missing values in my dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which is about 1.4m rows x 16 columns, there are no missing values in the dataset but instead there are some string or text like `"+AC0-5.3"` instead of just empty or `'NaN'` .

The numerical values after `'AC0-***'` are different for different entries but they all start with `'+***-***'`. How to deal with this? I guess dropping all rows wherever there's such entries would be a good idea.

**I tried a solution from stack-overflow:**

```
dataset = dataset[~dataset['total+AF8-amount'].astype(str).str.startswith('+')]
```

Which helps remove all the rows that had an entry of that missing value. The problem is that it only checks the missing values in the target column which is `'total+AF8-amount'`.

I want to remove all the rows where there is this weird missing value in any column, how can I accomplish this?
This the training set .head()
sorry for the bad formatting every space refers to the next column,

```
ID  vendor+AF8-id   pickup+AF8-loc  drop+AF8-loc    driver+AF8-tip  mta+AF8-tax distance    pickup+AF8-time drop+AF8-time   num+AF8-passengers  toll+AF8-amount payment+AF8-method  rate+AF8-code   stored+AF8-flag extra+AF8-charges   improvement+AF8-charge  total+AF8-amount
0   1   170 233 1.83    0.5 0.7 04-04-2017 17.59    04-04-2017 18.05    1   0   1   1   N   1   0.3 9.13
1   2   151 243 3.56    0.5 4.64    04-03-2017 19.03    04-03-2017 19.20    1   0   1   1   N   1   0.3 21.36
2   2   68  90  1.5 0.5 1.29    04-03-2017 15.06    04-03-2017 15.12    2   0   1   1   N   0   0.3 8.8
3   2   142 234 1.5 0.5 2.74    04-04-2017 8.10 04-04-2017 8.27 1   0   1   1   N   0   0.3 14.8
1656    2   114 255 3.96    0.5 3.92    04-05-2017 22.57    04-05-2017 23.22    2   0   1   1   N   0.5 0.3 23.76
1657    2   230 100 0   **+AC0-0.5**    0.51    04-06-2017 8.14 04-06-2017 8.18 1   0   3   1   N   0   **+AC0-0.3  +AC0-5.3**
1658    2   163 226 0   0.5 3.93    04-07-2017 4.06 04-07-2017 4.20 1   0   2   1   N   0.5 0.3 15.8
1659    2   229 90  2.56    0.5 2.61    04-07-2017 13.49    04-07-2017 14.06    2   0   1   1   N   0   0.3 15.36
```

**For example the row with ID 1657 have a those missing entries, there are other such rows. This is what i have done:**

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('chh-OLA-Kaggle.csv', index_col = 'ID')
testset = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col = 'ID')
dataset.dropna(axis = 0, subset = ['total+AF8-amount'], inplace = True)

dataset = dataset[~dataset['total+AF8-amount'].astype(str).str.startswith('+')]
X = dataset.iloc[:, :15].values
y = dataset['total+AF8-amount'].values
```

One more problem arises is that now all those values  is of type 'str', how to make all columns of numerical values to type 'float64' so that I could fit it to a model.

Are all datasets like this?

Comment: put a snippet of you input & expected out put (you can put them in between ``` & ```)

Comment: how to do that, I just creates this account :(

Comment: as i said. put those between ``` & ```. i wil ledit your question to put some dummy data, you can re-edit it with your data (just cop paste from your dataset)

Comment: @SamiranKonwar, do you want floating values  like `5.3` from  `+AC0-5.3` ?

Comment: place it into your Post.

Comment: @pygo No, I want to remove every rows that have this weird value, there's very few of them.

Comment: @SamiranKonwar show us some rows of what you are talking about. paste it into the past where it says `Input Data`

Comment: @pygo DONE!, I'd like to ask, are all datasets like this? can we even ask this question?

Comment: Sorry i was away, please see my answer, i borrowed the example dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, this is been answered but still i found a way to do it different way which i used 3 years back from the So itself which is more intuitive and good to have..

`str.contains('+')` matches the beginning of any string, Since every string has a beginning, everything matches. Instead use `str.contains('\+')` to match the literal `+` character.

Therefore we can use `for col in df` for every column by calling the `str.contains` on it to get the values with `np.column_stack()` as a boolean masking and save it and then later applying it using the `dataFrame.loc()` along `row-wise(asis=1)`.

### Example DataFrame:

```
>>> df
    col1    col2    col3
0   32.1    33.2    +232
1   34.2     3.4     3.4
2  32.44    +232   32.44
3   +232    1.32    +234
4  1.312  131.23  131.23
```

### Solution:

```
>>> mask = np.column_stack([df[col].str.contains(r"\+", na=False) for col in df])

>>> df.loc[ ~ mask.any(axis=1)]    
    col1    col2    col3
1   34.2     3.4     3.4
4  1.312  131.23  131.23
```

### Solution 2:

Without `np.column_stack` purly with pandas but it returns dataframe obj while earlier with numpy returns `numpy.ndarray` which is best fit for boolean masking.

```
>>> mask = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(r'\+', na=False))
>>> df.loc[ ~ mask.any(axis=1)]
    col1    col2    col3
1   34.2     3.4     3.4
4  1.312  131.23  131.23
```

In case you need to apply `float`, try following..

```
df.loc[ ~ mask.any(axis=1)].astype(float)
```

### Note:

Since you asked, the use of `~` used as boolean vectors to filter the data. other operators are: `|` for or, `&` for and, and `~` **for not**. These must be grouped by using parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to count how many rows have this type(starts with '+-***) of entries.if they are less then you can simply drop those rows.

If not then you should perform data cleaning operation on each row.For that you can use apply() method.pass axis=1 in apply()

Comment: there's very few rows who have this type of entries, the code above removes all these rows wherever there was such entries of the target column, but I guess with would be difficult to perform imputation on independent vairables with such entries as well so how to remove the rows where ever there's such entries no matter the column. A little modification the that above code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

Example dataframe:

```
     Col1    Col2    Col3
0    32.1    33.2    +232
1    34.2     3.4     3.4
2   32.44    +232   32.44
3    +232    1.32    +232
4  1.3123  131.23  131.23
```

You want to remove rows from any column that starts with `+` and also make sure you convert them back to `float64` to pass it to your model. Then do:

```
for x in df.columns:
    df = df[~df[x].astype(str).str.startswith('+')]
    df[x] = df[x].astype(float)
```

If you do not want to loop over all columns, you can just pass the column names in a list instead of df.columns.

Final output after getting rid of rows having entries starting with +:

```
      Col1    Col2    Col3
1  34.2000    3.40    3.40
4   1.3123  131.23  131.23
```

Output of `df.info()` showing they are now in `float64` type:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 1 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Col1    2 non-null float64
Col2    2 non-null float64
Col3    2 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3)
memory usage: 64.0 bytes
```

Comment: can you explain me the line ```df = df[~df[x].astype(str).str.startswith('+')]``` what's '~'

Comment: What you did was for one column but what I am doing is for multiple columns. I am looping through all the columns and checking if for each column there is any row which starts with + and drop them. In the next line, I am converting back to float. This repeats until we are done looping through all the columns. So, you will automatically get rid of all rows across all columns where your value starts with + and bring them back to float64 format. Was that clear? If not, what is that you find trouble understanding?

Comment: it is very clear, very professional , my problem is solved, thanks. :)

Comment: Glad to know that. If the answer has helped you solve your purpose, please consider marking it as accepted as it can help others later. :)